# @OneToOne make primary key as foreign key at the same time (Spring JPA/Hibernate)

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, one-to-one

I've an entity like this:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

The `id` is not autogenerated, but decided by the user.

I have a second entity like this:

```
@Entity
public class PersonDetail {

    @Id
    @OneToOne
    private Long id; // should be referred to id of Person entity
    // or maybe private Person person; ???

    private String language;
    private Integer age;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

Also in the second entity, the `id` is not autogenerated.

I would like to make a `@OneToOne` relationship, and I would like that the `id` of `PersonDetail` is the primary key of `PersonDetail` but at the same time it must be a foreign key to the `Person` entity (`id` field).

Is it possible with Spring JPA / Hibernate annotations ?

Thanks a lot,
Andrea

Comment: This blog post describes how to do what you want: https://vladmihalcea.com/2016/07/26/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Answer (score 5):

You can follow this wiki: 
[Primary Keys through OneToOne and ManyToOne Relationships](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Primary_Keys_through_OneToOne_and_ManyToOne_Relationships)

Re-write your `PersonDetail` entity to this:

```
@Entity
public class PersonDetail {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Person person;

    private String language;
    private Integer age;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Why have you introduced separate `id` field in `PersonDetail`?

Comment: As any entity must have an Id attribute.

Comment: Why not use `@Id` and a simple `@JoinColumn` on `person` field?